# Using Headphone socket for monitor speakers

Tags: speakers

I have a Yamaha YDPS51 digital piano. Whilst the internal speakers are acceptable I'm unable to get a rich deep sound from them. The problem is that I don't have any outputs apart from 2 headphone sockets. Is it safe to connect monitor speakers with a sub woofer to this socket?

Cheers 
Rob

Answer (score 4):

I have never used the Yamaha YDPS51 before, but I have connect powered speakers to my Casio and Korg headphone jacks and it has worked fine. The simple answer to your question is **yes**, it is *safe* and worth a try. Although you might experience a loss in sound quality or even a distorted sound due to impedance mismatch. It also depends on the kind of speakers you are working with. It should work better with standard low-voltage left and right audio speakers. Good luck and let me know how it goes!

Comment: I like your emphasis on "safe" versus "will sound good".

Answer (score 1):

It may well work- if you connect pure speakers from the headphone socket, the volume may not be loud, but the quality will be better. If your speakers are powered (as in computer monitors) then as long as you start with the output volume low, it will probably give a good sound. You may even have an input on your hi-fi, which could give a good sound, too.
If you bought one, or better still two, little practice amps, as in guitar type, they would connect either as you say, or through the left/right output, to give a really good sound, loud enough for a rather large room.

Answer (score 0):

It will be safe.  It will probably even sound good.  The old advice would have been all about mis-matched impedences and the inevitability of distortion. But modern gear is much more tolerant.  Outputs are generally low impedence (a headphone output certainly will be) and inputs are high impedence. Start with the output level of the piano low, the volume of the speakers about half-way.